# regex exclude numbers that have letter at the beginning and at the end

Tags: regex

I am having RegEx for special serial numbers. I need to extract serial numbers from string and the conditions are:

- has only numbers
- length>4

Some examples:

```
DC10# 02414/334567 / A234567
2P# 718231xdcs 11111
1P# C182313
```

I am getting this right now:

- 02414,334567
- 718231xdcs, 11111

Currently I have RegEx that is validating if serial number is starting with letter and than excludes it, also I am checking the length, but I cant get it working in case when letter is at the end, for example 718231xdcs

Correct answer would be:

- 02414,334567
- 11111

My RegEx is:

```
/(?<![A-Za-z0-9.])[0-9.]{4,}+/
```

I am stuck with the letter at the end.

Comment: Why do you have the dot `.` in your number regex `[0-9.]{4,}+`? The dot character matches everything except for the newline `\n` and some other special characters in regex.

Comment: You might want to check for word boundaries but I don't get what you exactly want or why you made this specific regex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a word boundary before and after the pattern which matches atleast 4 digits .

```
\b\d{4,}\b
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/eN2hY4/20)

**Explanation:**

- `\b` Matches between a word character and a non-word character.
- `\d{4,}` Matches atleast 4 digits.
- `\b` Word boundary.

Comment: I came up with the same idea, and proved it works on a regex test website, but couldn't get it to work in PowerShell. Even on a simplified example `02414/334567" -match "\b(\d{4,})\b"`. Your answer helped me see that I don't need the `()` group (I was getting two identical results - one was the whole match and one was the group!), and that I need to look for the 'global' modifier. Turns out `-match` does not support it, and the alternative is to use `[regex]::matches($text, $pattern)`. Slightly off-topic, but eh.

Comment: sorry i don't know about powershell codes. Did your powershell supports lookahead and lookbehind?